# mdui metadata extension with spring-saml

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

i need to configure an SP with Spring SAML Extension, this time with a new idp admin request. 
He ask me to send him metadata with mdui values like this:

```
<md:SPSSODescriptor> <Extensions>  <mdui:UIInfo>
<mdui:DisplayName xml:lang="it">desc</mdui:DisplayName>
<mdui:InformationURL xml:lang="it">http://xxxx</mdui:InformationURL>
</Extensions>
....
</SPSSODescriptor>
```

I think i can do this operation with a non signed metadata with values added by hand.
It is the only way or can i obtain the same result with configuration options ?
thanks in advance.

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the MetadataGenerator class of spring-security-saml. It has a buildExtensions method that is populating OpenSAML's Extensions object with the DiscoveryResponse extension if configured. You could possibly extend MetadataGenerator and hook in your configuration.

This is an excerpt of the buildExtensions method:

```
protected Extensions buildExtensions(String entityBaseURL, String entityAlias) {

    boolean include = false;
    Extensions extensions = new ExtensionsBuilder().buildObject();

    // Add discovery
    if (isIncludeDiscoveryExtension()) {
        DiscoveryResponse discoveryService = getDiscoveryService(entityBaseURL, entityAlias);
        extensions.getUnknownXMLObjects().add(discoveryService);
        include = true;
    }

    if (include) {
        return extensions;
    } else {
        return null;
    }

}
```

If you're using Spring Boot you can use this library to configure SAML and provide the custom MetadataGenerator: [spring-boot-security-saml](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml)

The configuration would look something like:

```
    @Configuration
    public static class MyServiceProviderConfig extends ServiceProviderConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(ServiceProviderSecurityBuilder serviceProvider) throws Exception {
            serviceProvider
                .metadataGenerator(customGenerator);
        }
    }
```